# how to create an array of objects OR use models, just like we have in a JSON - Angular/Ionic

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```js
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { __core_private_testing_placeholder__ } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ModalController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matchfixer',
  templateUrl: './matchfixer.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matchfixer.page.scss'],
})
export class MatchfixerPage implements OnInit {
  id1: any;
  id2: any;
  url: string;
  fixture: any[]=[];
  venue: any[]=[];
  venueUrl: any;
  player: any[]=[];
  playerUrl: any;
  toss: any[]=[];
  teams: any[]=[];
  
  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    public http: HttpClient,
    public navCrl: NavController
    ) {}

  async delay(ms: number) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms)).then(()=>console.log('fired'));
    }

  goconsl(){
    console.log(''+this.id1+''+this.id2);
  }

  goback(){
    this.navCrl.pop();
    this.navCrl.navigateRoot('/home');
  }

  fetchVenue(){
    this.fixture.forEach((item,index) => {
      if(item.status!='NS'){  
      this.venueUrl='https://cricppp.herokuapp.com/users/venue/'+item.venue_id;
      this.http.get(this.venueUrl).subscribe(response => {
        this.venue[index]=response["name"];
        //this.venue[index]=response;
        console.log('venue '+this.venue[index]+' '+index);
      });
    }
    else
    {
      this.venue[index]='no venue/no match';
      console.log('venue '+this.venue[index]+' '+index);
    }
    });
  }

  fetchPlayer(){
    this.fixture.forEach((item,index) => {
      if(item.status!='NS'){  
      this.playerUrl='https://cricppp.herokuapp.com/users/player/'+item.man_of_match_id;
      this.http.get(this.playerUrl).subscribe(response => {
        this.player[index]=response["fullname"];
        console.log('player '+this.player[index]+''+index);
      });
    }
    else
    {
      this.player[index]='no pop/no match';
      console.log('player '+this.player[index]+''+index);
    }
    });
  }

  fetchToss(){
    this.fixture.forEach((item,index) => {
      if(item.status!='NS'){  
      this.http.get('https://cricppp.herokuapp.com/users/teams').subscribe(response => {
        this.teams=response["teams"];
        this.teams.forEach((itm,indx) => {
          if(itm.id==item.toss_won_team_id){
            this.toss[index]=itm.name;
            console.log('toss '+this.toss[index]+''+index);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    else
    {
      this.toss[index]='no toss/no match';
      console.log('toss '+this.toss[index]+''+index);
    }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.storage.get('team1Id').then(paras1 => {
      this.id1=paras1;
    });
    this.storage.get('team2Id').then(paras2 => {
      this.id2=paras2;
    });
    this.delay(1000).then(any=>{
      this.url = 'https://cricppp.herokuapp.com/users/fixtures/'+this.id1+'/'+this.id2;
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
        this.fixture = response["allFixtures"];
        console.log(this.fixture[0].note);
        this.fetchVenue();
        this.fetchPlayer();
        this.fetchToss();
        });
    });
  }

}
```

here i have 3 final arrays player[]. toss[]. & venue[]
i wanted to display them sequentially in the html using ngFor but ngFor can iterate through 1 array only
(i wanted to display them like `- player[0]->toss[0]->venue[0] ------- player[1]->toss[1]->venue[1]...`
and so on...

i was looking into models and/or array of objects but i cant get anything to work, i want to have a model like

```
export class Data{
    public venue: string;
    public toss: string;
    public player: string;
    }
```

but since i am new, i can't get it to work, whenever i try to assign data by using forEach it shows error `this.data[index]` is undefined.
(i am doing data: `Data[]=[];`) (i also imported the model)
i hope i am explaining correctly, i wanted to create an array where each element has 3 propertied venue, toss and player to which i can assign values.
like `this.data[index]="response from API";`
just like a json has, i also tried looking into array of objects but i cannot get it to work.
i also read about services but i cant get this simple thing to work so i couldn't handle service either.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are making multiple asynchronous calls which might finish fetching data at different times.

So, identifying that you have received all the data from all the calls is tricky. You might want to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), or RxJS's [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), 
or something similar.

Assuming all the data is fetched and is available, you can either create a new `Data[]` array as you wanted. Or if all those arrays are same length, then you can just iterate through all of them at the same time.

`*ngFor` iterates over an iterable object such as array, but you can use the index to access values from other arrays too.

For example,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of player; let i = index">
  <div>player[i]</div>
  // Can use the same index on other arrays.
  <div>toss[i]</div> 
  <div>venue[i]</div> 
</ng-container>
```

But if arrays are of different length, then you will get `undefined` values.

I didn't see the code where you are pushing data to `data[]` array, but you could do something like

```
var data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
  data.push({
    "venue": venue[i],
    "toss": toss[i],
    "player": player[i]
  });
}
```

And then use `*ngFor` to iterate over this `data[]` array to display the values.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let value of data; let i = index">
  <div>data[i].player</div>
  <div>data[i].toss</div> 
  <div>data[i].venue</div> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: fetching data at different time is also not a problem in my case, the app that i am making isn't some major thing, i just need that the data gets there so i could show it using data binding whenevr it's available.
promise and rxjs are little outta my scop rn, i'm learning still.

Comment: Yes, but knowing that the data is available is not easy in your case. If you try to use the data before it is available, you will run into will run into `undefined` errors. Rendering the view also throws errors, but as a quick and dirty fix you can use  `*ngIf` with multiple boolean flags.

Comment: i didn't know ngFor can be used to iterate over other arrays.
arrays are at same length (in the end)
"I didn't see the code where you are pushing data to data[] array" - thats because i couldn't do it.
i will try these you suggested and report back, thank you!

Comment: the promise/forkjoin was too complex for me.
the second method works with how i want to display the data. thank you.
i tried the last method to push and that also worked, i however find the previous one simpler, thank you for these 2 solutions.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You can learn about promises and observables as you gradually progress. You're welcome. I'm glad it helped.